# 'custom pagination' issue with wordpress theme after a 4.41 update

Tags: wordpress, pagination

After nearly all day researching this, Ive discovered that there is a known WordPress bug that causes problems in some themes with pagination. It occurred after the upgrade to wp 4.4.1. Mine just so happens to be one of those effected. Some people saw a **404 error** when they tried to go to mysite.com/page/2 of their pagination, I however just see the same content as `page/1`.

I've tried following two other posts that suggested I add in these snip-its to the bottom of the `functions.php`:

```
add_filter(‘redirect_canonical’,’custom_disable_redirect_canonical’);
 function custom_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url){
      if (is_paged() && is_singular())
         $redirect_url = false; 
         return $redirect_url;
 }
```

and

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'category_posts_per_page', 10, 1 );
function category_posts_per_page( $q_obj ) {
    if( is_category() )
    $q_obj->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 1; // Change this example value
}
```

Neither worked. Here is my code. Hopefully someone else familiar with this known issue can help.

```
/*---------------------------------
    A custom pagination function
------------------------------------*/

if ( ! function_exists( 'krown_pagination' ) ) {

    function krown_pagination( $query = null, $paginated = false, $range = 2, $echo = true ) {  

        if ( $query == null ) {
            global $wp_query;
            $query = $wp_query;
        }

        $page = $query->query_vars['paged'];
        $pages = $query->max_num_pages;

        if ( $page == 0 ) {
            $page = 1;
        }

        $html = '';

        if( $pages > 1 ) {

            $html .= '<nav class="pagination">';

            if ( ! $paginated ) {

                if ( $page + 1 <= $pages ) {
                    $html .= '<a class="prev" href="' . get_pagenum_link( $page + 1 ) . '">' . '<i class="krown-icon-arrow_left"></i>' . __( 'Older Post' ,'krown' ) . '</a>';
                }

                if ( $page - 1 >= 1 ) {
                    $html .= '<a class="next" href="' . get_pagenum_link( $page - 1 ) . '">' . __( 'Newer Post' ,'krown' ) . '<i class="krown-icon-arrow_right"></i></a>';
                }

            } else {

                for ( $i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++ ) {

                    if ( $i == 1 || $i == $pages || $i == $page || ( $i >= $page - $range && $i <= $page + $range ) ) {
                        $html .= '<a href="' . get_pagenum_link( $i ) . '"' . ( $page == $i ? ' class="active"' : '' ) . '>' . $i . '</a>';
                    } else if ( ( $i != 1 && $i == $page - $range - 1 ) || ( $i != $page && $i == $page + $range + 1 ) ) {
                        $html .= '<a class="none">...</a>';
                    }

                }

            }

            $html .= '</nav>';

        }

        if ( $echo ) {
            echo $html;
        } else {
            return $html;
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.